# Where can I get xfwm4-themes on Xubuntu 19.10

Tags: xubuntu, themes, 19.10

When using Xubuntu I always installed the package xfwm4-themes as I really liked the good old nostalgic themes like Redmond, Platinum, etc. I am unable to find this package in 19.10 in the main repos these days though, so I was wondering where one can find this package.

Comment: Possibly, most of these themes are obsolete since xfce largely moved to GTK3

Comment: There is a short list of possibly useful sites here: https://wiki.xfce.org/howto:install_new_themes

Answer (score 7):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xfwm4-themes&searchon=names), the *xfwm4-themes* package is no longer available in the standard 19.04 and 19.10 repositories. And that makes sense because it's been [dropped from Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/xfwm4-themes) in December 2018 for being unmaintained.

### Alternative 1

I would suggest looking at the themes available in the 19.10 repositories. Many of them provide their own *xfwm4* theme and it's likely that these themes will be appropriate for your system.

### Alternative 2

You can visit [xfce-look.org](https://www.xfce-look.org/browse/cat/138/order/latest/) and click on XFCE/XFWM4 Themes to get a listing of themes. I suggest you choose from recently updated themes to ensure compatibility.

[image: xfce-look.org]

I downloaded the Neon_Knights_Blue .tar.xz archive, extracted it, and placed it in ~/.themes.

Then, I opened *Settings > Window Manager* and could choose it from there.

[image: Selecting the new xfwm4 theme]

### Alternative 3

You can still find the *xfwm4-themes* in archived form online. For example, there's [git.xfce.org/archive/xfwm4-themes/](https://git.xfce.org/archive/xfwm4-themes/) from which you can download `xfwm4-themes-4.10.0.tar.gz` from **eight years** ago.

- extract the contents
- open the `redmond` folder
- create a folder called `xfwm4` in the `redmond` folder
- move all the `.xpm` files and the `themerc` file into the `xfwm4` folder
- move the `redmond` folder into `~/.themes`, which you'll need to create if it doesn't exist.
- open *Settings > Window Manager* and choose `redmond`
- applications that use GNOME's client-side decorations will obviously not use any  xfwm4 theme.

**Using the redmond xfwm4 theme**

[image: redmond xfwm4 theme on 19.10]

Answer (score 1):

The package in question was last part of Xfce 4.10.  The currently shipping version of Xfce 4.14 does not include it and [the current development tree does not have it either](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/log/).  If you want something like that to return you need to raise the point at a Xubuntu meeting like [the most recent one](http://ubottu.com/meetingology/logs/xubuntu-devel/2019/xubuntu-devel.2019-11-15-23.00.log.html) where development issues were discussed both for Xubuntu and upstream Xfce.